# Hyperlink images in Microsoft word in a table

Tags: microsoft-word

In Microsoft word, I would like to create a table and insert hyperlinked individual unique images in each box, or cell. Upon clicking any of the hyperlinked images, unique individual Word docs will then open for each selection. Currently, an inserted image defaults to a general area of the table, but not in a targeted box or cell, and is far larger than any available box, or cell in the table.  How can I insert images so that they are located in a particular box, or cell so that they remain within the boundaries of each chosen box or cell on the table?

Comment: By default when clicking inside a table cell and doing Insert>Pictures it will insert the image inside the cell. What are the steps you're taking to insert the images? Also, when you click on the picture and go to the Picture Format tab, what is the *Wrap Text* set to? [Edit your question to add more details](https://superuser.com/posts/1783394/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Pasting an image from the clipboard into a table cell or the body of
the document will not resize the image automatically to fit inside the cell
or document margins. Only the **Insert Picture** command initiates
Word's auto-rescale process to margin settings which includes table cells.

To insert pictures into a table and resize the picture,
instead of the table, requires these steps:

- In the *File > Options > Advanced* dialog, go to the section
  "Cut, copy, and paste" and set "Insert/paste pictures as" to
  "In line with text"
- For the table, go to the tab *Table Properties > Table > Options*,
  uncheck "Automatically resize to f‌it contents" and click OK
- In *Table Properties > Row / Column / Cell*,
  specify the sizes

With these settings, pictures inserted with the **Insert Picture**
command will resize within the margins of their cell.
Pasting and dropping from Explorer will *mostly* work,
but not always.

The Word add-on of
[AuthorTec Insert Docs and Pics](https://www.greatcirclelearning.com/authortec-insert-docs-and-pics)
($7 with trial) may add more options.